# rsync: How to transfer Ubuntu local file to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-storage, rsync

I think I already finish the setting up of rsync, provided by online documentation, although I'm not sure have I really succeeded.

How to use rsync to transfer Ubuntu local file to Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you message it looks like you could be using your system's [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). If you want to move your file to Google Cloud Storage use [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync). For example

```
gsutil -m rsync -nr directory gs://your-bucket-name/
```

`-m` Causes rsync to upload files [in parallel](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

`-n` Causes rsync to run in "dry run" mode, i.e., just outputting what would be copied or deleted without actually doing any copying/deleting.

`-r` Causes directories, buckets, and bucket subdirectories to be synchronized recursively.

Comment: Thank you! I did it, and it said `Building synchronization state... Starting synchronization... Would copy file: .....` Then what should I do? I can't find those files in my google storage.

Comment: The poster mentions that the answer he provided is just an example of what you can do. That particular example did not copy anything since it was a "dry run". The full list of commands is available in the link that was provided above. If you want to actually copy those files, just remove the -n flag, and basically run this: gsutil -m rsync -r directory gs://your-bucket-name/

Comment: Thank you!! Succeed! Good for you!